# How to change an image's coordinate and size which embedded in a frame with wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, size, coordinate

I have a question about changing an image's coordinate and size with wxpython.

Could you please give me any demo?

Thanks a lot.

Below is my python program, but it doesn't work.

```
    image = 'resources/white_dot.png'

    bmp = wx.Bitmap(image, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)

    wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bmp, pos = event.GetPositionTuple())
```

Comment: How about [wxPython demo](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython2.8-win32-docs-demos-2.8.12.1.exe)?